# Showing a 0-100 range input with a min of 30 but still show the 0-30 area on the input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, range

I'm trying to create a HTML range slider that goes from 0-100, with a minimum attribute of 30.

The standard functionality of a range slider with a minimum attribute is to set the left most part of the range to the minimum attribute.

```js
$('input[type="range"]').on("input change", function() {
  $('span').html($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="30" />
<span></span>
```

Is it possible to still have the range slider go from 0-100 but have a scrollable area from 30-100 instead to achieve something like the image below please?

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid not, but you could fake it

Comment: `oninput='if(value<31)value=30'`   http://jsfiddle.net/9arnn359/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example: http://codepen.io/zvona/pen/pJWJrp with plain JS:

```
var range = document.querySelector('input[type=range]');
var value = document.querySelector('span');
var breakpoint = 30;

range.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
  this.value = (this.value >= breakpoint) ? this.value : breakpoint;
  value.textContent = this.value;
}, false);
```